# Spring boot Data JDBC + Querydsl error " Reason: No property count found for type"

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jdbc, querydsl

I'm trying to use Spring data JDBC with Query DSL in Kotlin.
This is my repository

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository : PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Int>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<User> {}
```

My entity is a simple data object

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
data class User(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_id_seq", sequenceName = "user_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    val id: Int? = null,
    val name: String,
    val surname: String)
```

I've added these lines to my build.gradle

```
implementation("com.querydsl:querydsl-sql-spring:4.4.0") {
        exclude group: 'joda-time', module: 'joda-time'
    }
kapt "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.4.0:jpa"
```

I've added the `@EnableJdbcrepositories` annotation in my Spring application

But when I try to start my application I get this error:

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in my.tests.querydsl.repositories.UserRepository defined in @EnableJdbcRepositories declared on 
JdbcRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJdbcRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract long org.springframework.data.querydsl.QuerydslPredicateExecutor.count(com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate)! Reason: No property count found for type User!
```

I tried also to remove `@EnableJdbcrepositories` annotation but the error persists.
What I'm doing wrong? I'm missing some dependency?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Infobip Spring Data Querydsl](https://github.com/infobip/infobip-spring-data-querydsl) provides QuerydslPredicateExecutor fragment support for Spring Data JDBC (among other things).

With it, `UserRepository` definition should work as is defined, check out the module [README.md JDBC section](https://github.com/infobip/infobip-spring-data-querydsl#JDBC) for details.
If you need `SQLQuery`, `SQLUpdateClause` or delete with `Predicate` support don't miss the [QuerydslJdbcFragment](https://github.com/infobip/infobip-spring-data-querydsl/blob/master/infobip-spring-data-jdbc-querydsl/src/main/java/com/infobip/spring/data/jdbc/QuerydslJdbcFragment.java).

Answer (score 0):

The [Spring-Data](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449323952) book says that only Spring Data JPA and MongoDB support `QuerydslPredicateExecutor`

Comment: Sorry maybe it wasn't clear but I'm trying to use Spring Data JDBC https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl

Comment: Yes, I understood. I think the documentation is wrong. Try https://github.com/infobip/infobip-spring-data-querydsl